# NSNumber being recognized as NSString in if-else

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsnumber

I have this bit of code thats got me crazy.  Its a cellForRowAtIndexPath displaying 4 properties, of which 2 are NSStrings and 2 are NSNumber:

```
//THIS LOGS THE OBJECT BEFORE PROCESSING
NSLog(@"NO DATE EDITING");
NSLog(@"eFK: %@, eFN: %@",editedFieldKey, editedFieldName);
NSLog(@"editedObject vWA is:%@", editedObject);
NSLog(@"Is of type NSString?: %@", ([editedFieldKey isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])? @"Yes" : @"No");
//THIS TESTS TO SEE IF ITS A NSSTRING
if ([editedFieldName isKindOfClass:[NSSTRING class]]) {
    NSLog(@"its nsstring");
    textField.text = [editedObject valueForKey:editedFieldKey];
    NSLog(@"its NOT nsstring");
    }
} else {
//ELSE ITS A NUMBER SO GET ITS STRING VALUE BEFORE ASSIGNING
    textField.text = [[editedObject valueForKey:editedFieldKey] stringValue];
    // And we set the switch to ON if YES, OFF if NO...
    if ([editedObject valueForKey:editedFieldKey]) {
        NSLog(@"itemreceived equal to 1");
        itemReceived.on = YES;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"itemreceived equal to 0");
        itemReceived.on = NO;
}
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

I have 4 fields, 2 NSStrings and 2 NSNumbers.  When I tap on the string fields, I get its a string and it works fine.  But if i click on one of the number fields, I get its a string and NSCFNumber isNaturallyRTL...unrecognized selector sent to instance at the:

```
textField.text = [editedObject valueForKey:editedFieldKey];
```

Why is my test failing?  Why even when I select a number, which is not a string, the app goes thru the first if condition as if it were a string?

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the complete, exact error messages printed by your program, instead of just telling us part of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm. This is just a guess... But first:

```
NSLog(@"Is of type NSString?: %@", ([editedFieldKey isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])? @"Yes" : @"No");
```

Here, you look at `editedFieldKey`.

```
if ([editedFieldName isKindOfClass:[NSSTRING class]]) {
```

Here you are looking at `editedFieldName`. In neither case, I looks like as if your were testing the actual value.

Comment: This is exactly what it turned out to be.  a few seconds after posting it i realized that and now its working perfectly.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If I had to guess, I'd say you're testing the type of the wrong variable. Instead of:

```
...
if ([editedFieldName isKindOfClass:[NSSTRING class]]) {
...
```

Just based on your variable names (as your question is a bit lacking in details), it seems you instead want:

```
...
if ([[editedObject valueForKey:editedFieldKey] isKindOfClass:[NSSTRING class]]) {
...
```

*I left your typos in the snippets - this can't be compiling though. Aren't you actually using `[NSString class]` instead of `[NSSTRING class]`? Note the capitalization difference.*